# Extracting aws region from s3 event data in python (lambda)

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I trying to extract the aws region parameter from the s3 event data, I have already extracted the the bucket name and the key but I am unable to get the aws region or print the whole  event data

`source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']`
`key_created = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']).decode('utf8')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the json structure of an S3 event available [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html).

sth like below should do the trick (untested)

```
event['Records'][0]['awsRegion']
```